# Error: Could not resolve the package 'flutter_localizations' in 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart'

Tags: flutter

Now I am add international in my apps of flutter, this is my international dependencies in `pubspec.yaml`:

```
intl: ^0.16.1
```

and this is the `cruiseNavigatorHome` define in `intl_en.arb`:

```
"cruiseNavigatorHome":"Home",
  "@cruiseNavigatorHome":{
    "description": "A description about how to view the source code for this app."
  },
```

and this is the getting text in the apps code:

```
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/cruise_localizations.dart';

return Scaffold(
    body: viewService.buildComponent("homelist"),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label:CruiseLocalizations.of(context).cruiseNavigatorHome),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.follow_the_signs), label: '关注'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.rss_feed), label: '频道'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.school), label: '我的'),
        ],
        currentIndex: state.selectIndex,
        fixedColor: Colors.blue,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
        unselectedItemColor: Color(0xff666666),
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed),
  );
```

but when I run this project, give me this error:

```
Error: Could not resolve the package 'flutter_localizations' in 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart'.
    .dart_tool/flutter_gen/gen_l10n/cruise_localizations.dart:7:8: Error: Not found: 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart'
    import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
           ^
    .dart_tool/flutter_gen/gen_l10n/cruise_localizations.dart:162:5: Error: Getter not found: 'GlobalMaterialLocalizations'.
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    .dart_tool/flutter_gen/gen_l10n/cruise_localizations.dart:163:5: Error: Getter not found: 'GlobalCupertinoLocalizations'.
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    .dart_tool/flutter_gen/gen_l10n/cruise_localizations.dart:164:5: Error: Getter not found: 'GlobalWidgetsLocalizations'.
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Unhandled exception:
    FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:package%3Aflutter_localizations%2Fflutter_localizations.dart; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
    #0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:32:7)
    #1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:599:37)
    #2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:738:21)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:554:9)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #4      starter (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:180:12)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #5      main (file:///opt/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:13:24)
    <asynchronous suspension>


    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro.
```

what should I do to fix this problem? I am sure the class is right there.

[image]

Comment: Not sure is this helped? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49931

Comment: this advice avoid the problem. thank you!@JohnJoe

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the answer provided [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49931), you need to import `flutter_localizations` package too.

```
flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: 0.17.0-nullsafety.2
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is adding flutter_localizations package has very unexpected syntax. Provided official example confuses everyone as noone expect it that way inside pubspec.yaml. Like this:

```
 flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
```

And yes now pubspec.yaml file will have something like this (repeating sdk: flutter texts):

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
```

Plus you will need intl package:

```
intl: ^0.17.0
```

Official guide [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization)